# Modificar Barra Horizontal con CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy arreglando el diseño de una web, puedo cambiar el color y tamaño de la barra vertical usando `::webkit-scrollbar` y `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, pero en la web salen ambas barras tanto vertical como horizontal, que propiedad me permite cambiar el tamaño de la barra horizontal?

Comment: Le estás asignando una altura a esos pseudo-elementos? Si no es así, esa es la respuesta.

Comment: Ciertamente, lo estaba omitiendo, había aplicado un Width sin un heigth,

Comment: Si te sirvió dalo como respondida tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejemplo, tal como comentaba el compañero: @TSLucho

```
<style>

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: red;
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 5px;
}

</style>
```